# Two UITableView in CellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I am having Tableview with different Tags.
151 and 61.

If my tableview is having tag 151 I am creating cell and adding all stuff frame etc etc in it,
If my tableview tag is 61 then I have to create other cell with other parameters.

So in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` what I am doing is below code..

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:optionCellIdentifier];
    if (quizTableView.tag ==151)
        {
           if (cell == nil)
            {
                 /////Allocating cell here
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:optionCellIdentifier] autorelease];
                ///doing Stuff here.....
            }

          return cell;
        }
    if (quizTableView.tag ==61)
        {
           if (cell == nil)
            {
                /////Allocating cell here
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:optionCellIdentifier] autorelease];
                ///doing Stuff here.....
                but my control is not coming here...
            }

         ///managing values here.

          return cell;
        }
    }
```

My control i going in tableView with tag 61, and it checks for `if(cell == nil)` reruns false and come out from the loop.
But I need to alloc the cell there, so that I can manage them,
I tried the removing if condition but didn't help.
Its not creating my tableview cells.
But My tableView is getting created.
I cross checked it by giving background colour to UITableView. 
But my cell is not getting created.

Why this is do..
what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: "but my control is not coming here..." do you have return before that?

Comment: @MobileProjectLab :- yes

Comment: You are assigning cell in your first line of code: `cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:optionCellIdentifier];`, so you're cell is not equal to nil. You are also always checking the `quizTableView` tag, and I assume you want to be checking the `tableView` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:optionCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
         cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:optionCellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }


    if (quizTableView.tag ==151)
    {
       ///doing Stuff here.....
    }

    else if (quizTableView.tag ==61)
    {
        ///doing Stuff here.....
    }
        return cell;

}
```

Comment: :- Thanks for this, It works for first phase. but my problem is next.
I am not able to set attributed text to UILabel on the cell.
As to use this I need to go for attributed NSString parsing, and that result in freezing of my app